# Why var with jagged array returned from webservice have type of string[] instead of int[][]

Tags: c#

I have a jagged array which is returned from my web service. I want to store it in a var but it has `string[]` type instead of `int [][]`. Why?

[WebMethod]

```
public int[][] tab(int[] licz)
{

     int [][] a = new int[6][];
      { int a0 = licz[0];

          a[0]=new int[licz[0]];
          a[1] = new int[licz[1]];
          a[2] = new int[licz[2]];
          a[3] = new int[licz[3]];
          a[4] = new int[licz[4]];
          a[5] = new int[licz[5]];
      }
      int k = 0;
      Random liczba = new Random();
      for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
      {
          for (int j = 0; j < licz[k]; j++)
          {
                a[i][j] = liczba.Next(0, 5);
          }
          k++;
      }


    return a;
}
```

and in main function

```
int[] liczkol = new int[6];

for (int z = 0; z <= 5; z++)
{
    string nazwa = "ileko" + z;
    liczkol[z] = int.Parse(((TextBox)FindControl(nazwa)).Text);
}
var a = usluga.tab(liczkol);
```

Var is of type `string []` instead of `int [][]`.

Comment: Maybe because it *is* a `string[]`. Who knows? Show us your code.

Comment: My mind reading isn't working. Can you please show your code?